# ClassCastException: com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper Websphere 8.5.5 Hibernate 4.2.19

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, websphere-8

I need obtain `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` but I always get `com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper` when I'm trying cast to `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` I get `ClassCastException`
I'm using: Websphere 8.5.5, Hibernate 4.19, Oracle 11g

My `persistence.xml`

```
       <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.jta.UserTransaction" value="java:comp/UserTransaction" />
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:comp/UserTransaction</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

ibm-web-bnd.xml

```
<resource-ref name="java:comp/UserTransaction" binding-name="java:comp/UserTransaction"></resource-ref>
```

My service

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
 public class ResourceService {
 ...
private UserTransaction userTransaction;
...
this.userTransaction = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext()
     .lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

`new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction")` always get `com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper` object and

```
EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation
of method "addResource" on bean "BeanId(testEar#test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#ResourceService, null)". Exception data: java.lang.ClassCas
tException: com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper incompatible  with javax.transaction.UserTransaction
```

instance of lookup method I'm trying get UserTransaction by means of

```
@Resource(name="java:comp/UserTransaction")
private javax.transaction.UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

after that I get

```
CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation
of method "addResource". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException:  Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentE
xception: Can not set javax.transaction.UserTransaction field  pl.example.was.test.service.ResourceService.userTransaction to com.ibm
.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper
```

somebody have any idea how can I get javax.transaction.UserTransaction ?

Thanks for help

Comment: In general `public class com.ibm.ejs.container.UserTransactionWrapper implements javax.transaction.UserTransaction` , so you should have no problem injecting that. Possible problem is that you are using Maven and you probably incorrectly including jta related jars in your applicatoin. Verify your build process and ensure that no jars provided by container are in your application.